# preventing HTML5 drag and drop function from multiple drops of the same element

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a drag and drop system with HTML5. Dragging images from the left side of the screen to the right side(these are identified as `window1` and `window2`. the images are stored in a array and appended to a hidden input element so I can send them to the next page through a `submit`. the problem is I only want the script to detect what's being dropped in `window2` and I don't want multiple entries.

```
function drop(ev)
{
//append the hidden child
number.toString();
var hidden = document.createElement("input");
hidden.type = "hidden";
hidden.name = "option"+number;
hidden.value = my_images;
var f = document.getElementById("select");
f.appendChild(hidden);
number++;

var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
ev.preventDefault();    
}
```

I was considering a simple `if statement` but what should I  look for? how do I check where I  am currently dropping the image?

EDIT: would it be an idea to use an `onmouseover` event to somehow check what element I'm currently hover over? if so how would I accomplish this? current I've written this small snippet of code

```
var current = document.mouseover;
current = document.getElementById(this);
```

Comment: can you call `if ev.target.children.length > 0` => mean there is some child already?

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu I tried running that above and it immediately triggers when I drop a image

Comment: When it already have a child, you may return false to disable the process?

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu doing so disables the whole dropping process not sure why or how to fix, increasing the 0 to 1 doesn't help

Comment: You mean when you drop multiple entries, just take the first one?

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu one image at a time, multiple images can be dropped into `window2` but when I drop the same image back into ` window1` and back into 2 again I get the following output "tree.jpg,tree.jpg"

Comment: Ok, let me check. It would be great if you can share code to http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu alright let's give it a shot never used that site before http://jsfiddle.net/UyDre/2/

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 spec does not account for dragging multiple items. As a result (and you appear to have noticed this above) the various HTML5 events will not indicate that multiple items have been dragged.

You don't explicitly say this within your question, but my guess is that you think (or thought, this is an older question) that multiple items are being dragged due to the "ghost" image generated automatically by the browser. These images certainly can give the impression that multiple elements are being dragged.

There are a number of known problems with these "ghost" images, and the way the browser generates them. Specifically that the ghost image is generated at the time dragging starts, which means that none of your code to define an appropriate drag has even run yet. I.e. the browser doesn't know if you are dragging one big giant element, a little element, or maybe you accidentally selected a lot of text right before the drag... it generates the image of whatever it sees, and that's what you get.

In some browsers (not IE) you can replace the drag image with something more appropriate. This usually works out if you don't care about IE, but if you do care about IE then you have just found out why people are annoyed by the HTML5 API.